# When i try to show dialog box it gives me FORCE CLOSE error

Tags: android, android-intent, android-dialog

Here is the code to show my dialog box activity. Whenever i try to open this intent my app get force close.so please tell me the mistakes in my code.And here is the logcat.

> 03-28 12:11:36.851: E/AndroidRuntime(681): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 03-28
>   12:11:36.851: E/AndroidRuntime(681): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.neelrazin.noteit/com.neelrazin.noteit.Password}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 03-28 12:11:36.851:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(681):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
>   03-28 12:11:36.851: E/AndroidRuntime(681):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
>   03-28 12:11:36.851: E/AndroidRuntime(681):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) 03-28
>   12:11:36.851: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
>   03-28 12:11:36.851: E/AndroidRuntime(681):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 03-28
>   12:11:36.851: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 03-28 12:11:36.851:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(681):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 03-28
>   12:11:36.851: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-28
>   12:11:36.851: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 03-28 12:11:36.851:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(681):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   03-28 12:11:36.851: E/AndroidRuntime(681):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 03-28
>   12:11:36.851: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-28 12:11:36.851:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(681): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 03-28
>   12:11:36.851: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at
>   com.neelrazin.noteit.Password.onCreate(Password.java:57) 03-28
>   12:11:36.851: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   03-28 12:11:36.851: E/AndroidRuntime(681):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)

```
public class Password extends Activity {

    final Context context = this;
     public Long mRowId;
     private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;
     String password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.password);


        mRowId = (savedInstanceState == null) ? null :
            (Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
        if (mRowId == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID)
                                    : null;
        }

         mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
            mDbHelper.open();
          Cursor notesC = mDbHelper. fetchNote( mRowId);
            startManagingCursor(notesC);
            final String pass = notesC.getString( notesC.getColumnIndex("passw") );


         // custom dialog
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.password);
            dialog.setTitle("Enter Password");

            final EditText enterpass = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtext);

            Button ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
            ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    password= enterpass.getText().toString();
                    if(password.equals(pass.toString())){

                        Intent i= new Intent(getBaseContext(),NoteEditor.class);
                          i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID,mRowId);
                            startActivity(i);
                    }

                }
            });

            Button dialogButton = (Button)          dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonCANCEL);
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();  
    }
```

Comment: which is line 57 of your code?

Comment: what is line number 57 in Password.java ?

Comment: ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  this is my line 57 in password.java in eclipse

Comment: please check your context is not null...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Here :

```
Button ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);//<<
```

you forget to call `setContentView` for Activity before accessing Views from it. set layout for Activity in `onCreate` of Activity as :

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //<<<
   .....
```

or if `dialogButtonOK` button is inside Dialog then use Dialog instance to initialize `ok` button as :

```
Button ok=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
```

Comment: but i already set the content....see the line where DIALOG starts "dialog.setContentView(R.layout.password);"

Comment: @Razin : where you are setting Content for Activity ? because using `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.password);` line u are setting content for Dialog instead of Activity

Comment: yeah thanks its work :) and can u tell me when i click on cancel how can i get back to my previous activity??

Comment: @Razin : use StartActivity after `dialog.dismiss();` for starting prev Activity or call `Current_Activity.this.finish();` for finishing current Activity and start prev one

Answer (score 2):

Seem error on `Buttonok` because initialization is done in a wrong way,

This way!:

> Button ok=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);

Instead:

> Button ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);